# Can't Pass 1 VLAN Through Trunk

Tags: cisco, vlan, trunk

I have 2 Cisco switches running IOS with VLANS 20,30,40,50. On SWITCH1 I have servers on Ports 1,2&3 on VLAN 30. I also have a laptop on port 5 on the same VLAN 30 and can ping the servers.  They can ping each other fine. I have port 24 trunked from SWITHCH1 to SWITCH2 with Port 30 allowed through the trunk. On SWITCH2 I have port 5 on VLAN30. If I move the laptop from SWITCH1 to SWITCH2 on port 5 I can't ping the servers. As stated the VLAN is passed through the Trunk. Why can't I ping my servers?

TRUNK PORT CONFIG

```
Interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/24
switchport trunk native vlan 100
switchport trunk allowed vlan 20,30,40
switchport mode trunk
switchport nonegotiate
ip arp inspection trust
service-policy output QOS_POLICY_SWITCHPORT
ip dhcp snooping trust
```

ACCESS PORT CONFIG

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
switchport access vlan 30
switchport mode access
switchport block unicast
storm-control broadcast level bps 62m
storm-control unicast level bps 1g
spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
spanning-tree bpduguard enable
spanning-tree guard root
```

Comment: Please add the switches' full configurations to your question. As it is, we can't see the 2nd trunk port or what else might interfere (port access security, MAC filter, ACLs, ...).

Comment: Did you create the VLANs on the switches? I do not mean the SVIs (`interface Vlan30`). I mean with the global VLAN command (`Vlan 30`), not the interface command.

Comment: @Zac67 due to security concerns I can't put full configs per company policy. Configs are the same on each switch.

Comment: @Ron Maupin yes VLAN 6 is created on both switches. It shows up in both show vlans.

Comment: What do you see in the switch's MAC tables of VLAN30 regarding the two addresses trying to communicate?

Comment: Just because it shows up does not mean you took the step of configuring the global `Vlan <VLAN>` command. That is often a missed step that causes strange problems.

Comment: Do the following commands to troubleshoot:

'show spanning-tree' and look for the spanning-tree and forwarding states for each interface in question.

'show int trunk' and make sure the interfaces you expect are actually in trunk mode and what VLANs are allowed/forwarding.

'show vlan brief' and make sure the VLANs exist on all switches and are accessible on ports you want.

'show logging' to make sure no errors happen when the ports come up/link.

Do those on both/all switches to make sure they all agree.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer thanks for the commands. The Trunk between the SWITCHA and SWTICHB shows for VLAN30 BKN* and *ROOT_INC. Not sure what this means. SWITCHA has `spanning-tree vlan 30 priority 0` and SWITCH B is priority 32775

Comment: OK So the problem is the root guard. The Root for VLAN 30 is on SWITCHA but the root for VLAN 20 and 40 is on SWITCHB. Can root guard still be enabled per VLAN or does it have to be on an interface and ensure the roots are set correctly?

Comment: I have also been setting VLAN priority. There seems to be an issue with understanding root and priority 0. What is the diffference between root and priority 0?

Comment: First thing I would do would be to make sure logs are enabled for the logging buffer and then take down the link in question and then bring it back. If it is being blocked, there should be some log entry, hopefully meaningful. BKN means 'broken', which should only happen with a serious misconfiguration. Otherwise we need to see at least the full config of the 2 interfaces (each side of the link). Switch A can't be the root (even with priority 0) if it is BKN on that spanning tree instance. Root guard might be the issue. If B is set to root guard but A is priority 0, you have an issue.